# Query with layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have been working on layout lately. There are two image shown. First one shows what I need and Second one shows what I get.

[image]

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve this with **LinearLayout**.
And when I say LinearLayout that means **no layout_weight or RelativeLayout** need to be used. I know using these two will simplify my work, but I want why through my code its not achieved. Below is my code for XML.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mytext" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_alarm"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/ibutton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As far as i cant tell, its not possible without using `layout_weight` or different layout(RelativeLayout)

Comment: Why don't you want to use layout_weight?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is not possible to get a layout shown in 1st pic by using just one `LinearLayout`. Can you mention specific reason why you don't want to use `RelativeLayout`?
Such layouts can easily be made using single `RelativeLayout`. May be there is a workaround for the situation which is restricting you to use `RelativeLayout/layout_weight`.

Comment: Your line "First one shows what I need and Second one shows What I want" is a bit ambigous. Could you please make it clear which layout do you actually want? 1st or 2nd image?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you can reply with the situation you are facing then may be we can arrive at some solution for this.

Comment: At this position I can say that the screen shot which I have shown is just a beginning. I have much more complex structure. So weights will ultimately give "Nested weight is bad for performance" and relative will make it clumsy. I want it as simple as possible.And Sorry I wont b able to give entire screen shot

Comment: Actually RelativeLayout gives more flexibility than any other Layout and it's really not that clumsy :). Moreover if you know your layout will become more complex going forward then I would strongly suggest you to use RelativeLayout. Performance wise LinerLayout is better but if your layout is complex then you would need more LinearLayouts than RelativeLayouts to construct the same layout.
Also, this particualr requirement doesn't mandate use of 'weight' and can be done using single RelativeLayout as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by adding a dummy View with layout_weight="1" and layout_width="0dp" between the the views I want on the left of the parent and those I want on the right. This will expand to fill the space, assuming the other views have no weight. Crude but effective.

Comment: Hey thanx for answer, but as I stated earlier I don't want to use weight or relative. and reason I have xplained in Gagan's comment. I need some alternative...

Comment: ok but I thought I'd put my answer anyway since I know that others have the problem as stated (minus the 'no layout_weight' stipulation).